# Multiple Where Parameters on EntityDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, entitydatasource

I have a gridview that uses an entity datasource to populate itself. Depending on what the user has access to see, I want the gridview to implement a where clause. At the lowest level of access, the user can only see themselves. In order to do this I implement the line of code:

```
EmployeeEntityDataSource.Where = "it.Person_ID = " + selectQuery.ToString()
```

This successfully reduces the data in the gridview to the one appropriate user. If the user has the next step in access, they should be able to see themselves plus all the employees that work for them. I have sucessfully created a list of employees Person_IDs and I'm trying to filter my gridview so that if the Person_ID column in the gridview matches one of the Person_IDs in my list it should show up.

I have tried the following bits of code:

1.

```
For Each employeeID In employeeList
    If count2 <> count Then
        whereString += "it.Person_ID = " + employeeID.ToString() + " OR "
        count2 += 1
    Else
        whereString += "it.Person_ID = " + employeeID.ToString()
    End If
Next

EmployeeEntityDataSource.Where = whereString
```

Essentially thought I could create a giant where statement with a bunch of ORs but this did not work

2.

```
EmployeeEntityDataSource.WhereParameters.Add(employeeList)
EmployeeEntityDataSource.Where = "it.Person_ID = @employeeList"
```

The error I get here says a List(of T) cannot be converted WebControl.Parameter

How do I properly create a WHERE statement that will compare the it.Person_ID of the gridview to each element in my list called employeeList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I lied When I said my first bit of code did not work. The issue was that I was not generating the massive OR statement correctly.

From what I remember the statement I was originally generating was it.Column = ID1 OR ID2 OR ID3 and so on.

If the statement created is it.Column = ID1 OR it.Column = ID2 OR it.Column = ID3 and so on, this creates a statement that works properly.

The code that is working in my current project is:

```
For Each employee In employeeList
    If count2 <> count Then
        whereString += "it.Person_ID = " + employee.ToString() + " OR "
        count2 += 1
    Else
        whereString += "it.Person_ID = " + employee.ToString()
    End If
Next

EmployeeEntityDataSource.Where = whereString
```

Comment: Please use this URL to get the IN statement working

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251205/entitydatasource-where-clause-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

I think an In statement should accomplish what you need. Something like this -

```
string employeeIDs = string.Join(",", employeeList.ToList());
EmployeeEntityDataSource.Where = String.Format("it.Person_ID IN ({0})", employeeIDs);
```

Or you may have to iterate through your list to create the employeeIDs string, depending on the types we're dealing with here.

Comment: I edited your code to work with Visual Basic (I think this is for C#)

Dim employeeIDs As String = String.Join(",", employeeList)
EmployeeEntityDataSource.Where = String.Format("it.Person_ID IN ({0})", employeeIDs)

I get the error "The query syntax is not valid. Near term ',', line 8, column 21."

Comment: It looks like this might be an inherent issue in Entity Framework. Take a look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/where-in-clause?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: It seems they made it work out of the box with EF4 according to the second reply. I am have a tough time figure out how to get my employee list in the where statements as it requires a string and I want to pass in a variable to it.