# EntityDataSource WHERE IN

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a `asp:EntityDataSource`

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=MyEntities"  DefaultContainerName="MyEntities" 
    EntitySetName="Student" Where="it.Age = 12 or it.Age = 13"> 
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

now I need to show more ages. Is there a way to write that shorter?

My try:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=MyEntities"  DefaultContainerName="MyEntities" 
    EntitySetName="Student" Where="it.Age IN (11,12,13,14)"> 
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

but that throws an error

> The right argument of the set expression must be of CollectionType.

Comment: What about:  `Where="it.Age >= 11 and it.Age <= 14"`

Comment: @NawedNabiZada good idea but there are also gaps in my real application

Comment: I am not so familiar with asp.net but shouldn't the array be in `{ }` instead of `( )` ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada yes but  that's not `C#` and it's also not `SQL` syntax

Comment: AFAIK, `EntityDataSource.Where` certainly requires braces rather than parentheses: `Where="it.Age IN {11,12,13,14}"`. The reason behind the braces still unknown, but some outside reference mentions it.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Please add this as an answer (because it's correct), so we see this question has been taken care of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to use `IN` clause on `Where` attribute of `EntityDataSource` is putting curly brace block surrounding all values like array declaration:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=MyEntities"  DefaultContainerName="MyEntities" 
    EntitySetName="Student" Where="it.Age IN {11,12,13,14}"> 
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

The reason behind usage of curly braces possibly depends on [ObjectQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303(v=vs.110).aspx) which receives typed query against model on given context, which may accepts array of values. In other words, the IN clause have equivalent on LINQ format as this:

```
int[] ages = new int[] {11, 12, 13, 14};
var query = MyEntities.Student.Where(it => it.Age.Contains(ages));
```

And generated SQL command would become:

```
SELECT * FROM [MyEntities].[Student] WHERE Age IN (11,12,13,14)
```

Other possible reason is server control syntax in ASPX page markup follows XSLT convention regarding [attribute value templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985169.aspx), which interprets curly brace blocks as string-value expression and parentheses treated as method parameter/expression enclosure (see [XSL transformation details](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#patterns)).

Similar issue:

[EntityDataSource Where Clause in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251205/entitydatasource-where-clause-in-vb-net)

Additional reference:

[Creating IN Queries](http://rob.conery.io/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/)